# Call to EntityFrameworkCore’s (on SQLite) .Migrate() method fails when calling database context from Xamarin.Forms UI

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I’m working on a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform App project and I’m willing to use EF Core on my models to enable code-first migrations on my future versions. I managed to generate an initialization migration by using an ad-hoc .Net Core app as I needed a runtime environment for this task (see further details at ngrumbine’s demo https://github.com/ngrumbine/EFDemo).

The problem is that when launching my solution on iOS and Android emulators, the application crashes when reaching the call to the EF Core migration application method (DatabaseFacade.Migrate : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-3.0)

It happens here:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence
{
    public class EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private string _databasePath;

        public EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext(string databasePath)
        {
            _databasePath = databasePath;
            Database.Migrate();
        }

        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_databasePath}");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasIndex(f => f.Uri)
                .IsUnique(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the _databasePath attribute, and it is correctly initialized. Moreover, when using the debugger, the call to OnConfiguring(...) passes successfully, and the failure comes from an unreachable code part. 
This happens at the same stage on both iOS and Android platforms, but with quite different stacktraces (see the bottom of this post).

Concerning the context: the mainpage view constructor tries to load a list of items from the database repository, which triggers the failling call to the database contexts factory.

Mainpage view xaml.cs code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace EFCoreMigrationIssue
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private FooRepository fooRepository;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fooRepository = new FooRepository();
            RecordUri = new Command(() => AddFooToRepository(),
                canExecute: () => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Uri));
            LoadFooList();
        }

        internal ObservableCollection<Foo> FooList { get; private set; }
        internal ICommand RecordUri { get; private set; }
        internal string Uri { get; set; }

        private void LoadFooList()
        {
            FooList = new ObservableCollection<Foo>(fooRepository.GetAll());
        }

        private void AddFooToRepository()
        {
            var foo = new Foo(Uri);
            fooRepository.Add(foo);
        }

    }
}
```

With my model Foo being :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence
{
    [Table(nameof(Foo))]
    public class Foo 
    {
        public Foo(string uri)
        {
            Uri = uri;
        }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Uri { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the FooRepository being :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence
{
    public class FooRepository
    {
        public FooRepository()
        {
        }

        public void Add(Foo item)
        {
            using var context = GetDbContext();

            context.Foos.Add(item);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
        {
            using var context = GetDbContext();

            return context.Foos.ToList();
        }

        private EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext GetDbContext()
        {
            return new EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext(GetDbFilePath());
        }

        private string GetDbFilePath()
        {
            var filename = "database.db3";
            return Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

The initial migration to be applied (automatically generated):

```
// <auto-generated />
using EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;

namespace EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext))]
    partial class EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.0.1");

            modelBuilder.Entity("EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.Foo", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                    b.Property<string>("Uri")
                        .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("Uri")
                        .IsUnique();

                    b.ToTable("Foo");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

**The complete source code of my crash-demo project can be cloned here : https://github.com/anucii/EFCoreMigrationIssue.git**

Stacktrace on iOS:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2 (SQLitePCL.utf8z
>   filename, SQLitePCL.sqlite3& db, System.Int32 flags, SQLitePCL.utf8z
>   vfs) [0x00000] in <20c60171f1e84dae90646bc69aa016a2>:0   at
>   SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_open_v2 (System.String filename,
>   SQLitePCL.sqlite3& db, System.Int32 flags, System.String vfs)
>   [0x0000e] in <20c60171f1e84dae90646bc69aa016a2>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open () [0x00122] in
>   <4595d52549d54c96abd42a829433f17f>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection
>   (System.Boolean errorsExpected) [0x00068] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open
>   (System.Boolean errorsExpected) [0x00042] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists
>   () [0x0000c] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists ()
>   [0x0000b] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate
>   (System.String targetMigration) [0x00012] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade) [0x00010] in :0   at
>   EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext..ctor
>   (System.String databasePath) [0x0000f] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext.cs:13
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.FooRepository.GetDbContext ()
>   [0x00001] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/FooRepository.cs:32
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.FooRepository.GetAll () [0x00001]
>   in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/FooRepository.cs:25
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.MainPage.LoadFooList () [0x00001] in
>   /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/MainPage.xaml.cs:36   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.MainPage..ctor () [0x0003e] in
>   /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/MainPage.xaml.cs:27   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.App..ctor () [0x0000f] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/App.xaml.cs:13
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching
>   (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00007]
>   in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.iOS/AppDelegate.cs:26
>   at at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)   at
>   UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr
>   principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86
>   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String
>   principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/13.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00001] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.iOS/Main.cs:17

Stacktrace on Android :

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000143
>   from typeref (expected class
>   'System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNullAttribute' in assembly
>   'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51')   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableReferencePropertyConvention.Process
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionPropertyBuilder
>   propertyBuilder) [0x00016] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.NonNullableReferencePropertyConvention.ProcessPropertyAdded
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionPropertyBuilder
>   propertyBuilder,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.IConventionContext`1[TMetadata]
>   context) [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ImmediateConventionScope.OnPropertyAdded
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionPropertyBuilder
>   propertyBuilder) [0x00057] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+RunVisitor.VisitOnPropertyAdded
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+OnPropertyAddedNode
>   node) [0x00011] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+OnPropertyAddedNode.Accept
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionVisitor
>   visitor) [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionVisitor.Visit
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionNode
>   node) [0x00005] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionVisitor.VisitConventionScope
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionScope
>   node) [0x00021] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionBatch.Run
>   () [0x000e6] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ConventionBatch.Dispose
>   () [0x0001d] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher+ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelInitialized
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder) [0x0006f] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelInitialized
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionModelBuilder
>   modelBuilder) [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model..ctor
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConventionSet
>   conventions) [0x0006d] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder..ctor
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ConventionSet
>   conventions) [0x00012] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext context,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure.IConventionSetBuilder
>   conventionSetBuilder) [0x00012] in
>   <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<GetModel>b__1
>   () [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   System.Lazy`1[T].ViaFactory (System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode
>   mode) [0x00043] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0   at
>   System.Lazy`1[T].ExecutionAndPublication (System.LazyHelper
>   executionAndPublication, System.Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>   [0x00022] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0   at
>   System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00074] in
>   <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0   at System.Lazy`1[T].get_Value
>   () [0x0000a] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext context,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure.IConventionSetBuilder
>   conventionSetBuilder) [0x00048] in
>   <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel
>   () [0x0003c] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model ()
>   [0x00020] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder+<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3
>   (System.IServiceProvider p) [0x00006] in
>   <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.FactoryCallSite
>   factoryCallSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context) [0x0000d] in <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSiteMain
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00033] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   serviceProviderEngine,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock
>   lockType) [0x00059] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   singletonCallSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context) [0x00029] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00057] in
>   <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ConstructorCallSite
>   constructorCallSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context) [0x0002c] in <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSiteMain
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument) [0x0004f] in
>   :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   serviceProviderEngine,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverLock
>   lockType) [0x00059] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   singletonCallSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext
>   context) [0x00029] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[TArgument,TResult].VisitCallSite
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite, TArgument argument) [0x00057] in
>   <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceCallSite
>   callSite,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope) [0x00012] in <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0
>   (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   scope) [0x0003e] in <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService
>   (System.Type serviceType,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
>   serviceProviderEngineScope) [0x0003d] in
>   <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService
>   (System.Type serviceType) [0x00013] in
>   <afb136dae6154b1f956a9d6c25d25974>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService
>   (System.IServiceProvider provider, System.Type serviceType) [0x00034]
>   in <f42dc3743e9a40bbad437e55b425d408>:0   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T]
>   (System.IServiceProvider provider) [0x0000e] in
>   <f42dc3743e9a40bbad437e55b425d408>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies ()
>   [0x00017] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider ()
>   [0x000b5] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance
>   () [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance
>   () [0x00000] in <42de1eb635af4acabe9ad4af5d123ec7>:0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.GetRelationalService[TService]
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure`1[T]
>   databaseFacade) [0x0000c] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate
>   (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade) [0x0000b] in :0   at
>   EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext..ctor
>   (System.String databasePath) [0x0000f] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/EFCoreMigrationIssueDbContext.cs:13
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.FooRepository.GetDbContext ()
>   [0x00001] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/FooRepository.cs:32
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence.FooRepository.GetAll () [0x00001]
>   in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Persistence/FooRepository.cs:25
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.MainPage.LoadFooList () [0x00001] in
>   /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/MainPage.xaml.cs:36   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.MainPage..ctor () [0x0003e] in
>   /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/MainPage.xaml.cs:27   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.App..ctor () [0x0000f] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue/App.xaml.cs:13
>   at EFCoreMigrationIssue.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle
>   savedInstanceState) [0x0002f] in /Users/dev3/Virtual
>   Machines.localized/shared/stackoverflow_samples/EFCoreMigrationIssue/EFCoreMigrationIssue.Android/MainActivity.cs:24
>   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr
>   jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr
>   native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in
>   <8c07a09624c14764b43f6b946a5a1f23>:0   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.8(intptr,intptr,intptr)

Comment: Same problem! For me it only happens in iOS! Did you find a workaround?

Comment: The problem disappeared for me by upgrading Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite from version 3.0.0 to 3.1.1

Comment: Hi! I eventually decided to use a local RealmDB instead. So no workaround found by my side, but thank you for the tips!

Comment: I completely understand your frustrations in using these libraries :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the

```
SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
```

in the very beginning of your app. I think it is only required for iOS, but I have put it in my App.xaml.cs constructor, no matter the platform:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // NOTE: The following line is required to load the platform specific assembly for SQLite.
    // See: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/wiki/SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init
    // And: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/597

    SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
}
```

See:

[SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/wiki/SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init)

and this GitHub issue:

[Workarounds for Xamarin.iOS app with EFCore 2.0](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/597)

As you have migrated to another database, I wish this would help others looking for the answer same as me!